# Improvement of Algorithm: Counting set bits in Byte-Arrays

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

We store knowledge in byte arrays as bits. Counting the number of set bits is pretty slow. Any suggestion to improve the algorithm is welcome:

```java
public static int countSetBits(byte[] array) {
    int setBits = 0;

    if (array != null) {
        for (int byteIndex = 0; byteIndex < array.length; byteIndex++) {
            for (int bitIndex = 0; bitIndex < 7; bitIndex++) {
                if (getBit(bitIndex, array[byteIndex])) {
                    setBits++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return setBits;
}
```

```java
public static boolean getBit(int index, final byte b) {
    byte t = setBit(index, (byte) 0);
    return (b & t) > 0;
}
```

```java
public static byte setBit(int index, final byte b) {
    return (byte) ((1 << index) | b);
}
```

To count the bits of a byte array of length of 156'564 takes 300 ms, that's too much!

Comment: Can you share the `getBit` method ?

Comment: I don't know if this may apply to your problem but maybe you could separately maintain the count.

Comment: please, share the `getBit` function

Comment: sorry, I added the missing methods..

Answer (score 5):

Try `Integer.bitcount` to obtain the number of bits set in each byte. It will be more efficient if you can switch from a `byte` array to an `int` array. If this is not possible, you could also construct a look-up table for all 256 bytes to quickly look up the count rather than iterating over individual bits.

And if it's always the whole array's count you're interested in, you could wrap the array in a class that stores the count in a separate integer whenever the array changes. (edit: Or, indeed, as noted in comments, use `java.util.BitSet`.)

Comment: Thanks! Just the Integer.bitcount() makes it 12 times faster! Probably I'll have a look later at the BitSet to

Comment: Be careful about using Integer.bitcount in this way, because if you have a byte that is 10000000, which is -128 in 2s compliment, and you pass that to Integer.bitcount, you will get 25 (not 1), because it requires to you cast to an int, which will auto-pad what it thinks is a negative number in 2s compliment.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the same global loop but instead of looping inside each byte I would simply use a (precomputed) array of size 256 mapping bytes to their bit count. That would probably be very efficient.

If you need even more speed, then you should separately maintain the count and increment it and decrement it when setting bits (but that would mean a big additional burden on those operations so I'm not sure it's applicable for you).

Another solution would be based on [BitSet implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/BitSet.java#BitSet) : it uses an array of long (and not bytes) and here's how it counts :

```
658        int sum = 0;
659        for (int i = 0; i < wordsInUse; i++)
660            sum += Long.bitCount(words[i]);
661        return sum;
```

Comment: Integer.bitcount() improves it!

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
    byte[] yourByteArray = ...
    BitSet bitset = BitSet.valueOf(yourByteArray);  // java.util.BitSet
    int setBits = bitset.cardinality();
```

I don't know if it's faster, but I think it will be faster than what you have. Let me know?

Your method would look like

```
 public static int countSetBits(byte[] array) {
     return BitSet.valueOf(array).cardinality();
 }
```

You say:

> We store knowledge in byte arrays as bits.

I would recommend to use a `BitSet` for that. It gives you convenient methods, and you seem to be interested in bits, not bytes, so it is a much more appropriate data type compared to a `byte[]`. (Internally it uses a `long[]`).

Comment: It's probably faster and saner if meant as a global replacement of OP's solution and not just for bit counting.

Comment: I have an improvement with Integer.bitcount(); BitSet.valueOf() is only available from java7

Comment: @myborobudur: Well, you didn't say you couldn't use Java 1.7 methods. But if you switch to `BitSet` completely (as I proposed) you won't need the `valueOf` method and can still use the fast `cardinality()`.

Answer (score 0):

By far the fastest way is counting bits set, in "parallel", method is called [Hamming weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight)
and is implemented in `Integer.bitCount(int i)` as far as I know.

Answer (score -1):

As per my understaning,

1 Byte = 8 Bits

So if Byte Array size = n , then isn't total number of bits = n*8 ?

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong

Thanks
Vinod

Comment: This provides the number of bits in the array, but the actual problem is to count the number of set bits in the array.